# Visual Studio Code can't detect AWS SAM CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

**-> Context**
I need to create, test and deploy AWS Lambda functions using Visual Studio Code. I have already met the prerequisites to setup everything and start:

- I have installed Docker latest version.
- I have installed AWS CLI and configure the profile credentials of my AWS account.
- I have installed AWS SAM CLI (latest version according to AWS documentation).
- I got the AWS Toolkit extension for VSCode.

I tried to detect the SAM CLI and also create a Lambda SAM Application from VSCode. It didn't detect the AWS SAM CLI, so I manually specify the location of the "sam.cmd" file in VSCode, but it kept getting errors. So far I'm having the same messages back and forward:

**-> AWS Toolkit logs messages**

- [WARN]:samCliLocator: found invalid SAM CLI (VersionNotParseable):**"Localaddress"**
- [INFO]: SAM CLI location (version: undefined): undefined
- [WARN]: telemetry: invalid Metric: "sam_detect" emitted with result=Failed but without the `reason` property. Consider using `.run()` instead of `.emit()`, which will set these properties automatically. See https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/blob/master/docs/telemetry.md#guidelines
- [INFO]: SAM CLI location (from settings): C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin
- [WARN]: samCliLocator: found invalid SAM CLI (VersionNotParseable): C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd
- [ERROR]: Error creating new SAM Application: 'Error: SAM CLI was not found [MissingSamCli]'

**-> VSCode Messages**
Apparently, there seems to be a problem with the version I'm using (version 1.109.0), VSCode keep giving messages such as:

- SAM CLI 1.85-1.86 has known issues on Windows (I have Windows 10), update SAM CLI.
- Cannot find SAM CLI.

Is there something I missed? I didn't configure something properly? Any information and feedback would be great.

....................

Comment: what is the output of this command run on cmd, looks like sam-cli is not installed properly,

          "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd" --info

Answer (score 0):

This log message is a hint:

> [WARN]:samCliLocator: found invalid SAM CLI (VersionNotParseable):"Localaddress"

As noted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031926/visual-studio-code-cant-detect-aws-sam-cli#comment137569126_78031926), AWS Toolkit depends on the result of `sam --info` to parse SAM CLI's version. Can you run this command and share the result?

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd" --info
```

It should look like this:

```
$ sam --info
{
  "version": "1.109.0",
  "system": {
    "python": "3.12.2",
    "os": "macOS-14.3.1-arm64-arm-64bit"
  },
  "additional_dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "available_beta_feature_env_vars": [
    ...
  ]
}
```